# Stuck on Hotel Salesperson Java Program

Tags: java

Here is the problem: A hotel salesperson enters sales in a text file. Each line contains the following, separated by semicolons: The name of the client, the service sold (such as Dinner, Conference, Lodging, and so on), the amount of the sale, and the date of that event. Write a program that reads such a file and displays the total amount for each service category. Display an error if the file does not exist of the format is incorrect.

Here is what I have:

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class practice1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter input file name: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter desired output file name: ");
    String outputFileName = console.next();
    console.useDelimiter(";");

    //Construct Scanner and PrintWriter objects for reading and writing

    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
    double dinnerTotal = 0;
    double conferenceTotal = 0;
    double lodgingTotal = 0;
    double total = dinnerTotal + conferenceTotal + lodgingTotal;

    //Read the input and write the output


    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        if(parts[2].equals("Conference")){
            conferenceTotal = conferenceTotal+ Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
        } else if(parts[2].equals("Dinner")){
            dinnerTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
        } else if(parts[2].equals("Lodging")){
            lodgingTotal += Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);


        }
    }

    out.printf("Dinner Total:", dinnerTotal);
    out.println();
    out.printf("Conference Total:", conferenceTotal);
    out.println();
    out.printf("Lodging Total", lodgingTotal);
    out.println();
    out.printf("Total", total);

    in.close();
    out.close();
    }


}
```

This program creates a new file that looks like this: 
Dinner Total
Conference Total
Lodging Total
Total

It doesn't print the actual totals though. How do I print the totals?

Comment: show the input file which you give?

Comment: When you do `double total = dinnerTotal + conferenceTotal + lodgingTotal;` you are summing up three zeroes.  Move it after your loop.

Comment: The program is computing total before getting the values from the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double total = dinnerTotal + conferenceTotal + lodgingTotal;` line needs to go below the `while` loop.

Comment: @user6115053 you can click the big check mark beside the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` requires a converter to work properly.

You should change:

```
out.printf("Dinner Total:", dinnerTotal);
```

to:

```
out.printf("Dinner Total: %f", dinnerTotal);
```

which will print the value you want. The other lines work similarly.

And, as @Atri pointed out,

```
double total = dinnerTotal + conferenceTotal + lodgingTotal;
```

should go after the loop so it gets calculated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to the replies: Your array index is wrong. Java arrays start at 0 so you need to shift all values with -1.

I got the code working with changing:

1. Array index
2. error in output code
3. move line that calculate total below the loop.

Comment: thanks for your help